# How to find any element inside <div> using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get value from `<div>` and `<span>` by using beautiful soup, any body guide me.

Comment: Post your code showing what you tried.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)? It explains how to go about selecting tags/text/etc: easily enough to get started.

Answer (score 5):

if you are considering that the next element is span you can take this example

```
spans = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'id':'titleDescriptionID'})
for span in spans:
    if span.string:
         "your code"
```